# Como usar o didSelectRowAtIndex?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableviewcell, uitableview

Gostaria de saber como utilizar `didSelectRowAtIndex`, mais especificamente gostaria de saber como cada *row* da minha `UITableView` chama uma `ViewController` especifica. No meu código abaixo, no caso gostaria que cada item do *array* que está na `UITableView` chame uma outra `ViewController`.

```
class ViewControllerAnalise: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var formulas = ["Participaçao de Capital de Terceiros", "Composiçao do Endividamento", "Imobilizaçao do Patrimonio Liquido", "Liquidez Geral", "Liquidez Corrente", "Liquidez Seca", "Giro do Ativo", "Margem Liquida", "Rentabilidade do Ativo", "Rentabilidade do PL"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ViewControllerCell2

        cell.formula.text = formulas[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return formulas.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eduardo, é bem simples mas depende também de como está a sua estrutura. Da forma que você explicou está bem superficial, então vou fazer algumas suposições.

Para isso, basta você identificar qual a célula pressionada e dizer qual a tela será aberta para cada situação.

Ficaria assim, por exemplo:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var viewController: UIViewController

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: viewController = ParticipacaoCapitalViewController()
    case 1: viewController = ComposicaoViewController()
    case 2: viewController = ImobilizacaoViewController()
    default: viewController = nil
    }

    if viewController != nil
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Aqui também eu estou supondo que você está usando `UINavigationController`, por isso o *pushViewController*, caso contrário vai ser necessário abrir de outra forma.

Comment: Neste caso voce passou o valor da celula para a segunda tela certo?, no codigo que postei tem uma array com 10 elementos, queria que quando clicasse em cada um dos elementos abrisse uma viewcontroller diferente, no caso tenho 10 viewcontrollers,e cada elemento chama uma. Nao entendi o DetalhesViewController. Desculpe mas ainda estou começando

Comment: Certo, fiz as alterações na minha resposta para adequar ao seu caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo aqui, :)

Comment: Perfeito, se esta resposta tiver sido útil, considere [marcá-la como resolvida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), assim ajudará outros com a mesma dúvida e a comunidade :)

Comment: Verdade, pode deixar o outro codigo aqui tbm? o de enviar o indexPath.row para outra viewController

Comment: Sim, daí dentro de cada `ViewController` você vai precisar de uma variável do tipo `Int`, e então basta definir, por exemplo, `viewController.itemIndex = indexPath.row` antes de dar o *push*.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, onde coloco a pergunta como resolvida?

Comment: Para marcar uma resposta como aceita, clique na marca de verificação ao lado da resposta para alternar da cor acinzentada para cor verde.